# Can I split up a long json_pack() into smaller ones?

Tags: c, json

new [jansson](https://jansson.readthedocs.org) user here. I am currently using json_pack, but I need to break it up in small pieces. This is what I have now (in reality many more fields):

```
elm = json_pack("{ s:s, s:s, s:s }", "field1", "value1","field2", "value2","field3", "value3");
```

result being:

```
{
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "field3": "value3"
}
```

I need to break this up in three calls, tried this, but it does not work:

```
elm = json_pack("{ s:s  }", "field1", "value1");
elm = json_pack("{ o, s:s }", elm, "field2", "value2");
elm = json_pack("{ o, s:s }", elm, "field3", "value3");
```

Expected result in elm the same as the first call above, but I end up with an empty object. Is what I want possible? Does anyone have an example?

Comment: you produce a json object with your pack expression. Where's the array?

Comment: Sorry, I meant object. Edited question.

Comment: actually I don't know json_pack, but I just read the `"o"` means, copy value as is, which then should lead to `elm = {{{"field1":"value1"}, "field2":"value2"}, "field3":"value3"}` which isn't even allowed. So possibly you get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently not, but I reverted to the old-school way:

```
elm = json_object();
json_object_set_new(elm, "fleld1", json_string("value1"));
json_object_set_new(elm, "fleld2", json_string("value2"));
json_object_set_new(elm, "fleld3", json_string("value3"));
```

This fixed my problem.

Comment: this is definitely more performant, better readable and symmetric. This is not old-school, but just better than using json_pack.